# Notation of the set of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I have a very simple question. Let $W$ be a vector space over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$. Now consider the set of subspaces of $W$:
$$\{V\:|\: V\subseteq W \; \text{is subspace}\;\}.$$
Is there a standard way of denoting this set? I've seen it denoted as $\mathcal{P}(W)$, but this seems very close to the power set of $W$. My question is, is there a standard way of denoting this set?

Comment: I don't even think that there is a standard way of denoting that $V$ is a subspace of $W$. (in an unambiguous way that doesn't depend on the context)

Comment: Right, without even a way to denote individually subspaces, I am not optimistic there is a way to denote all subspaces.

Comment: The Grassmannian can be thought of as the set of all subspaces of a particular dimension, but this comes with some topological structure which you probably aren't looking for.

Comment: I think it  is also preferable to say linear subspace, or vector subspace. Especially if you happen to be discussing topological vector spaces, because a topological subspace can be any subset. I've yet to see a specific notation for the set of all vector subspaces of a vector space.

Comment: So what I hear you saying is that there is no standard way of denoting this set, so I may choose to do it in whatever way I feel fitting?